# Can Google Appscript fetch information from a LDAP server?

Tags: shell, google-apps-script, ldap, ldap-query

I need to fetch a lot of information from LDAP server based on the data stored in a Google Sheet. Does google appscript have any library/module to do so?

If it was possible to execute shell commands in appscript like:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.org.website.com -x -D cn=root -w secret -LLL -b "o=myhost" cn=root
```

Then it would have been easier. Do you know of any work-around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no access to the shell in Apps Script. App Script does has HTTP and JDBC services. You would need to run one of those services as a bridge to your LDAP server.

> HTTP to LDAP:
>   https://serverfault.com/questions/372112/is-there-a-simple-ldap-to-http-gateway-out-there
>
> JDBC/LDAP driver:
>   http://www.openldap.org/jdbcldap/

Comment: to add: if the ldap is synced with a gapps domain, you may use the directory api from apps script to query some ldap fields.